# mutating a list of lists into a pyparsing.Dict structure

Tags: pyparsing

given:

```
innput = '''
(crossSectionDescriptor
    (layer 0
        (layerType SURFACE)
        (layerMaterial "AIR")
        (layerThickness 0)
        (layerElectricalConductivity 0)
        (layerThermalConductivity 0.00027)
        (layerDielectricConstant 1.000000)
    )
    (layer 1
        (layerType CONDUCTOR)
        (layerName "TOP")
        (layerMaterial "COPPER")
        (layerThickness 1.200000)
        (layerElectricalConductivity 595900.000000)
        (layerThermalConductivity 3.980000)
        (layerDielectricConstant 1.000000)
        (layerArtworkNegativeFlag FALSE)
        (layerIsShieldFlag FALSE)
    )
    (layer 2
        (layerType DIELECTRIC)
        (layerMaterial "FR-4")
        (layerThickness 8.000000)
        (layerElectricalConductivity 0)
        (layerThermalConductivity 0.012)
        (layerDielectricConstant 4.500000)
        (layerLossTangent 0.035)
    )
'''
innput_forced = '''
(crossSectionDescriptor
    (layer
        (0
            (layerType SURFACE)
            (layerMaterial "AIR")
            (layerThickness 0)
            (layerElectricalConductivity 0)
            (layerThermalConductivity 0.00027)
            (layerDielectricConstant 1.000000)
        )
        (1
            (layerType CONDUCTOR)
            (layerName "TOP")
            (layerMaterial "COPPER")
            (layerThickness 1.200000)
            (layerElectricalConductivity 595900.000000)
            (layerThermalConductivity 3.980000)
            (layerDielectricConstant 1.000000)
            (layerArtworkNegativeFlag FALSE)
            (layerIsShieldFlag FALSE)
        )
        (2
            (layerType DIELECTRIC)
            (layerMaterial "FR-4")
            (layerThickness 8.000000)
            (layerElectricalConductivity 0)
            (layerThermalConductivity 0.012)
            (layerDielectricConstant 4.500000)
            (layerLossTangent 0.035)
        )
    )
)
'''

def adjustmentNeeded( toks): # s, loc, toks are implicit
    adjustmentNeeded = True
    nodeNameSet = set()
    for tok in toks:
        if type( tok) is pp.ParseResults \
       and len( tok) > 2 \
       and type( tok[0]) is not pp.ParseResults \
       and type( tok[1]) is not pp.ParseResults \
           and restAreLists( tok[2:]):
              nodeNameSet.add( tok[0]) # silently rejects duplicates
        else:
            adjustmentNeeded = False
       #    break
    if adjustmentNeeded:
        # all tokens are lists of length 3 or more where the first element is the same value and the second element is not a list
        new_toks = [ nodeNameSet.pop()]
        for tok in toks:
            tok.pop(0) # removes redundant layer
            new_toks.append( tok.asList() )
        return( pp.ParseResults( new_toks ) )
    else:
        return( toks)

v_string = pp.Word(pp.alphanums+'_'+'-'+'.')
v_quoted_string = pp.Combine( '"' + v_string + '"')
v_number = pp.Regex(r'[+-]?(?P<float1>\d+)(?P<float2>\.\d+)?(?P<float3>[Ee][+-]?\d+)?'

nodeName = v_string
keyy = v_string
valu = pp.Or( [ v_string, v_quoted_string, v_number])

item  = pp.Group( pp.Literal('(').suppress() + keyy + pp.OneOrMore( valu) + pp.Literal(')').suppress() )
node = pp.Forward()  # recursive structure
node << pp.Dict( pp.Group( pp.Literal('(').suppress() + \
                                  nodeName + \
                                  pp.Optional( valu)('valu') + \
                                  pp.Dict( pp.OneOrMore( item ^ dict_node)).setParseAction( adjustmentNeeded) + \
                                  pp.Literal(')').suppress()
                        )
               ) #.setParseAction( makeAdjustments)

pprinter = pprint.PrettyPrinter( indent=1)
```

now using this:

```
pprinter.pprint(node.parseString(innput).asDict())
```

yields

```
{'crossSectionDescriptor': ['layer',
                            ['0',
                             ['layerType', 'SURFACE'],
                             ['layerMaterial', '"AIR"'],
                             ['layerThickness', '0'],
                             ['layerElectricalConductivity', '0'],
                             ['layerThermalConductivity', '0.00027'],
                             ['layerDielectricConstant', '1.000000']],
                            ['1',
                             ['layerType', 'CONDUCTOR'],
                             ['layerName', '"TOP"'],
                             ['layerMaterial', '"COPPER"'],
                             ['layerThickness', '1.200000'],
                             ['layerElectricalConductivity',
                              '595900.000000'],
                             ['layerThermalConductivity', '3.980000'],
                             ['layerDielectricConstant', '1.000000'],
                             ['layerArtworkNegativeFlag', 'FALSE'],
                             ['layerIsShieldFlag', 'FALSE']],
                            ['2',
                             ['layerType', 'DIELECTRIC'],
                             ['layerMaterial', '"FR-4"'],
                             ['layerThickness', '8.000000'],
                             ['layerElectricalConductivity', '0'],
                             ['layerThermalConductivity', '0.012'],
                             ['layerDielectricConstant', '4.500000'],
                             ['layerLossTangent', '0.035']]]}
```

which is heartbreakingly close to what I want

The goal here is to create a series of nested dicts.  I added a setParseAction function that massages a nodes'  subnodes into proper dicts.

This is just a small snippet of a much bigger file - I can't assume that 'layer' will always be the constant first element so can't codify that. In fact, if there was a way to use pp.addCondition() to say "one or more dict_nodes where each node has the same first token", that could be useful.

Any advice, pointers or constructive critism is all appreciated.

TIA,

code_warrior

Comment: I've made some progresss with a function that sees if a dict_node's tokens are ripe for reorganizing and if so builds up and returns a new ParseResults with the desired structure

Answer (score 0):

Define `node_name` so that it will recognize your "layer #" form, and give you back just the layer number:

```
layer_num = pp.Suppress('layer') + pp.Word(pp.nums)
nodeName = layer_num | v_string
```

By using '|' operator to give you a `MatchFirst`, you force pyparsing to try the `layer_num` expression first, and only accept a `v_string` if the `layer_num` expression fails.

You could also keep the 'layer' part of the index by defining `layer_num` to return the string 'layer_#':

```
layer_num = ('layer' + pp.Word(pp.nums)).setParseAction('_'.join)
```

This will give you layer indexes of 'layer_0', 'layer_1', etc.

Some other tips, may or may not be applicable, I don't fully know your data:

Try this for `v_string`:

```
# v_string = pp.Word(pp.alphanums+'_'+'-'+'.')
v_string = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + '_-.')
```

The way you define `v_string` with just a single argument, you would accept strings like '.....', '.--.-.---....-.-__', '234234.02340'. The 2-argument form forces v_strings to start with an alpha character, which is more likely to guard against other unwanted forms (would still accept something like 'abc.....', but this can be addressed too).

Pyparsing has a several provided quoted string expressions:

- sglQuotedString - string in single quotes
- dblQuotedString - string in double quotes
- quotedString - string in either single or double quotes

These expressions include the enclosing quotes as well, unlike the `QuotedString` class. If you want to remove them, add the pyparsing parse action `removeQuotes`.

```
# v_quoted_string = pp.Combine( '"' + v_string + '"')
v_quoted_string = pp.dblQuotedString
```

The new `pyparsing_common` namespace class contains several formats for matching common expressions, including integers, reals, IP addresses, etc. The numeric expressions are defined with conversion parse actions, so that the parsed values are already converted to Python ints and floats. `pyparsing_common` also includes two any-numeric expressions:

- number - matches int or real forms, and returns a value of the respective type
- fnumber - matches int or real forms, and returns all values as floats

Your `v_number` could be replaced with:

```
# v_number = pp.Regex(r'[+-]?(?P<float1>\d+)(?P<float2>\.\d+)?(?P<float3>[Ee][+-]?\d+)?')
v_number = pp.pyparsing_common.fnumber()
```

with the added benefit that the numeric values will be converted to actual floats at parse time.

Along similar lines, you can define a boolean type to match values such as `TRUE` and `FALSE`:

```
v_boolean = pp.Keyword('TRUE') | pp.Keyword('FALSE')
v_boolean.addParseAction(lambda t: t[0] == 'TRUE')
```

The parse action will convert 'TRUE' to Python True, and 'FALSE' to Python False. Then splice this into your expression for `valu`:

```
valu = v_quoted_string  | v_number | v_boolean | v_string
```

Lastly, I have always had a preference for MatchFirst over Or, as I think most cases where there are alternatives, they can be resolved unambiguously if tested in the correct order. Here is my version of `valu`:

```
# valu = pp.Or( [ v_string, v_quoted_string, v_number])
valu = v_quoted_string | v_number | v_string
valu = pp.MatchFirst([v_quoted_string, v_number, v_string]) # if you prefer
```

Since `v_number` and `v_string` do not accept leading quotes, checking for a quoted string first will not accidentally match when a number or unquoted string is intended. Similarly, checking for a number form before checking for a string will select the more specific expression over the catch-all match-any-combination-of-alphas-digits-dots-dashes-or-underscores. Conversely, `Or` will always test every given expression, and choose the longest match. I find this wasteful - if your `valu` encounters a quoted string, it will still try to parse it as a number and as an unquoted string, even though these matches are impossible.

Also, my personal taste is to use the pyparsing-defined operators: '|' for `MatchFirst`, '^' for `Or`, '+' for `And`, '&' for `Each`, '~' for `NotAny`. To me it makes the grammar more similar to the BNF, and more readable than explicit class construction calls with lists of expressions. But that is purely my own style - there is nothing wrong with the way you are writing your code.

Comment: I wish it were that simple. The nested nodes can themselves contain combinations of simple items and or nodes with and without values. The recursive nature of the nodes is complicating things. I'm thinking of defining groups of 1) simple items (which need no further processing), 2) nodes withOUT values ( which need no further processing, and finally 3) nodes with values( which will need special handling). Thus the *fn for setParseAction() can lock on to groups where the nodenames have values and convert the string to one overall node name with subgroups having values as keys.

Comment: I still think this can be done with proper definitions of `node` and `valu`. Have you written out a BNF? You've already started, in your enumeration of "what is a node?". This process can really help you organize your thinking first, then switch to coding mode and implement using pyparsing.